# Actionscript: Regular expression for file type checking

Tags: regex, actionscript

I want to **check** the file extension from the string using regular expression in action script.

By googling, I find [this](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.700.1.107/1/), but I'm week to regular expression.

Thanks.

Comment: Why using regular expressions, can't you use "standard" string functions ?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated @MatTheCat!

Comment: like `var str:String = "Testfile.txt"; 
var ext:String = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, str.length);`
@MatTheCat?

Comment: I don't know ActionScript but I think it should work, unless you want something else ?

Answer (score 0):

This regex is more reliable than the given example:

```
  ^[^\\?\/%*:|"><]+\.([^\\?\/%*:|"><]*)$
```

You can refer to the file extension as `$1` if you refer to it in replacement part.

You can refer to the file extension as `\1` if you refer to it in search part.

#### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the beginning of a line.
- `[^\\?\/%*:|"><]+\.` Matches any character except `\`, `?`, `/`, `%`, `*`, `:`, `|`, `"`, `>`, `<`, at least one character, until the last `.` character.
- `([^\\?\/%*:|"><]*)` Matches any character except `\`, `?`, `/`, `%`, `*`, `:`, `|`, `"`, `>`, `<`, as many as possible or none, and capture the bracketed part as group number `1`.
- `$` Assert position at the end of a line.